# Save data from a jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a sortable accordion loaded with a `foreach-template` loop over a `ko.observableArray()` named "Tasks".

In the accordion I render the `TaskId`, the `TaskName`, and a task `Description` - all `ko.observable()`.

`TaskName` and `Description` is rendered in input/textarea elements.

Whenever `TaskName` or `Description` is changed, an item is de-selected, or another item is clicked on, I want to call a function `saveEdit(item)` to send the updated `TaskName` and `Description` to the database via an ajax request.

I need to match the `TaskId` with the Tasks-array to fetch the actual key/value-pair to send to the `saveEdit()`.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion:{},template: {name: 'task-template',foreach: Tasks,afteradd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');}}"></div> 

<script type="text/html" id="task-template">
     <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}" class="group">
          <h3><b><span data-bind="text: TaskId"></span>: <input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName  /></b></h3>
          <p>
             <label for="Description" >Description:</label><textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
          </p>
     </div>
</script>
```

This is the binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var options = valueAccessor();
       $(element).accordion(options);
       $(element).bind("valueChanged",function(){
          ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element,valueAccessor);
       });
   },
   update: function(element,valueAccessor) {
      var options = valueAccessor();
      $(element).accordion('destroy').accordion(
      {
         // options put here....
         header: "> div > h3"
         , collapsible: true
         , active: false
         , heightStyle: "content"
      })
      .sortable({
              axis: "y",
              handle: "h3",
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                  var items = [];
                  ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                      //compare data('index') and the real index
                      if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                          items.push(this.id);
                      }
                  });
                  // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                  // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                  ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                  if (items.length) $("#sekvens3").text(items.join(','));
                  ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
              }
      })
      .on('stop', function () {
              $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
                  $(this).data('index', i);
              });
      })
      .trigger('stop');
   };
};
```

My first thought was to place the line

```
$root.SelectedTask( ui.options.active );
```

in an `.on('click')` event function where `SelectedTask` is a ko.observable defined in my viewModel.  However, the `.on('click')` event seems to be called a lot and it's generating a lot of traffic. Also, I can´t quite figure out where to put the save(item) call that sends the selected "item" from Tasks via an ajax-function to the database.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: can you add script in question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever TaskName or Description is changed, an item is de-selected, or another item is clicked on, I want to call a function saveEdit(item) to send the updated TaskName and Description to the database via an ajax request.

This sounds like the core of what you want to do.  Let's start out with a Task model

```
function Task (data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.description = ko.observable(data.description);
}
```

And then we need our View Model:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedTask = ko.observable();
    self.saveTask = function (task) {
        $.ajax({ ... });// ajax call that sends the changed data to the server
    };

    var taskSubscription = function (newValue) {
        self.saveTask(self.selectedTask());
    };
    var nameSubscription, descriptionSubscription;
    self.selectedTask.subscribe(function (newlySelectedTask) {
        if (newlySelectedTask instanceof Task) {
            nameSubscription = 
                newlySelectedTask.name.subscribe(taskSubscription);
            descriptionSubscription = 
                newlySelectedTask.description.subscribe(taskSubscription);

            self.saveTask(newlySelectedTask);// But why?
        }
    });

    self.selectedTask.subscribe(function (currentlySelectedTask) {
        if (currentlySelectedTask instanceof Task) {
            nameSubscription.dispose();
            descriptionSubscription.dispose();

            self.saveTask(currentlySelectedTask);// But why?
        }
    }, null, 'beforeChange');
}
```

So what's going on here?  Most of this should be pretty self explanatory so I'm just going to focus on the subscriptions.  We created a `taskSubscription` function so we're not constantly having it defined every time the `self.selectedTask` changes.

We have two subscriber functions.  The first fires after the `selectedTask`'s value has changed and the second fires before it changes.  In both, we verify that the new value is an instance of a Task object.  In the after change subscription, we set up two subscriptions on the `name` and `description` properties.  Then I capture the return value from the subscription function into two private variables.  These are used in the before change function to dispose of those subscriptions so that if those Tasks are ever updated when they're not currently selected, then we don't continue to fire off the saveTask function.

I've also added `self.saveTask` in each of the subscriptions to the `selectedTask` observable.  I asked why in here because, why save it if we don't know if the value has changed or not?  You may be making ajax requests needlessly here.

Also, as demonstrated by this code, you can set up these subscriptions to make ajax requests every time the value changes but that may end up making a LOT of requests.  A better option might be to set up functionality in your Task model that can track whether or not it is 'dirty' or not.  Meaning one or more of its values have changed that requires updating.

```
function Task (data) {
    var self = this;
    // Make a copy of the data object coming in and use this to save previous values
    self._data = data = $.extend(true, { id: null, name: null, description: null }, data);

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.description = ko.observable(data.description);
    for (var prop in data) {
        if (ko.isSubscribable(self[prop])) {
            self[prop].subscribe(function (oldValue) {
                data[prop] = oldValue;
            }, null, 'beforeChange');
        }
    }
}

Task.prototype.isDirty = function () {
    var self = this;
    for (var prop in self._data) {
        if (ko.isSubscribable(self[prop])) {
            if (self._data[prop] !== self[prop]())
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

And of course you need a way to save it, or make it not dirty

```
Task.prototype.save = function () {
    var self = this;
    for (var prop in self._data) {
        if (ko.isSubscribable(self[prop])) {
            self._data[prop] = self[prop]();
        }
    }
};
```

Using the same concept you can also create `Task.prototype.revert` that does the opposite of what `.save` does.  With all this in place, you could forego setting up the subscriptions on the individual `name` and `description` properties.  I wanted to show that option to just demonstrate how one might want to use the `.dispose` method on a subscription.  But now you can just subscribe to the `selectedTask` observable ('beforeChange') and see if the currently selected task that you're about to swap out isDirty.  If it is, call the `saveTask` function, and when that completes, call the `.save` function on the Task so that it is no longer dirty.

This is probably the route I would go in implementing something like this.  The beauty of it is, I haven't written a single line of code that has anything to do with the manipulating the View.  You can set the `selectedTask` any way you see fit.  What I would do is, bind the `selectedTask` observable to a click binding on the `<h3>` element inside of the accordion.  That way, every time a user clicks on any of the accordions, it will potentially save the previously selected task (if any of the property values had changed).

Hopefully that addresses your scenario here of trying to save a Task when certain events are triggered.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like your suggested solution. However the ko.isSubscribable(self[prop]) causes my script to stop.

Comment: Maybe because I populate my Tasks as a Viewmodel instance after collecting the initial data from the db via GetJSON:

            $.getJSON(
                "/myServiceGetAllTasks",
                "projectid=" + tp.ProjectId,
                function (allData) {
                    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                        return new TaskViewModel(item)
                    });
                    self.tasks(mappedTasks); 
              });

Comment: Regarding binding SelectedTask inside the accordion, I struggle to make it work. I´ve tried every possible element, both in the template and in the accordion-setup div itself. The "click" fires on initiation, but not when the task item is selected.

Comment: It's more of a rough sketch to give you some ideas on how to tackle your issue.  It's odd that your script should stop at the `isSubscribable()` check.  Unless `ko` or `self` is undefined, I'm not sure why that would happen.  What error do you get?  Looking at your `$.getJSON` call, when `mappedTasks` finishes, is that an observableArray?  If so, then then next line should be: `self.tasks(mappedTasks());`

Comment: With the accordion, I think, in order to set the `SelectedTask`, you're going to have to create an event handler that fires on the `beforeActivate` or the `activate` [event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) of the accordion. Then you have to see if `$(ui.newHeader)[0]` is 'truthy' and then do `self.SelectedTask(ko.contextFor($(ui.newHeader)[0]).$data)` if it is. You may have to futz around with the ui.newHeader or ui.oldHeader but the takeaway here is `ko.contextFor($(ui.xxxHeader[0]).$data)` gets you the task from that accordion panel.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing when I wrote those comment, because I thought I had tried everything, but eventually I got the desired outcome by - just as you said - hook the SelectedTask up following the attr-binding ( click: $root.SelectedTask ) in the id-part of my task-template.

Comment: With regards to the isSubscribable() show stopper, I must mention that I call Task = new TaskViewModel(item), where TaskViewModel = function(data) { var self = this; TaskId = ko.observable(data.TaskId); etc... } Then, push that Task onto self.Tasks.push(Task). MappedTasks is not a ko.observableArray, just an ordinary array as declared above.

Comment: maybe it isen't the ko.isSubscribable, but the self[pro] that is the issue, given my functional context?

Comment: try: `if (self.hasOwnProperty(prop) && ko.isSubscribable(self[prop])) { ... }`.  And you don't have to use ko.isSubscribable either.  You can use whatever logic that makes sense to you in order to determine if that's a property of the object that you want to look at to determine if the object is dirty or not.  You can use an array of strings that are the names of specific properties, or whatever you'd like.

Comment: Hi Dennis! It´s working now. Thanks!
I´ve got the SelectedTask hooked in my "task-template" like this:
<div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Scene' + SceneId}, click: $root.SelectedScene" class="group">

It cause it to be set quite often, so I will have to look into that, but changes are written to db when "self.SelectedTask().isDirty()" :)

Brilliant!

Comment: Great! If you don't want an observable to update as often, [throttle](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) it.

Comment: That´s an excellent idea! However, throttle the SelectedTask itself might not be a good idea as I might miss some selected task, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37553/discussion-between-dennis-and-asle-g)